# One Liner Shell script for finding all files in a path except a certain list of files

Tags: regex, shell, unix, sed

So say I have the following command :

```
find text except some files with name [a, b,c...]
```

The best I could do is :

```
`find -E PATH -type f -name “*.*” -and ! -name ".*" -not -path “FILE1”  -and ! -name ".*" -not -path “FILE2”`
```

But is there a way I could do it by not repeating `-and ! -name ".*" -not -path “FILE”` or is there a way I could get `FILE1`, `FILE2` etc. in a list?

Apologies if this is too simple, I have no experience at all with regexes.

Comment: if they share a pattern, you can use a regex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `find` with `-regex` for this:

```
find -E PATH -not -regex '.*/(\..*|FILE1|FILE2|FILE3)'
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending the need after the find

`find -E PATH -type f -name “*.*” -print | grep -E -v 'FILE1|FILE2'`

and with a big list of exclusion (best purpose) where Exclusion.File contain each eclusion per line

`find -E PATH -type f -name “*.*” -print | grep -E -v -f Exclusion.File '`